# Pruning partitions based on other columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Lets consider an orc table on hive with a partition on a `dt_month` column and it contains all rows for the days in a month (`txn_dt`).

Partition pruning will work when I when I introduce a where clause directly on the `dt_month` like below.

```python
df = spark.table("table")
df.where("dt_month = '2018-01-01'")
```

But is there a possibility for me to gather statistics on a partition level and prune partitions while filtering on the `txn_dt` (which is the column that `dt_month` is derived from) because there are some transitive properties that this holds towards the partition column?

```python
df = spark.table("table")
df.where("txn_dt = '2018-01-01'")
```

Can we make this query not run through the whole table and rely on orc indices but only the `2018-01-01` partition and then use the orc index?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Why not do `df.where("dt_month = '2018-01-01'").where("txn_dt = '2018-01-01'")`?

Comment: I knew I could do that. But I just wanted to know if there was an optimization where this would happen automatically. I have a framework where I can pass any column to filter based on and when its the right column then it could just be an incredible performance boost to use the partition as well.

Comment: I'm still not following why you can't just also specify the partition column in your filter. Keep in mind that you can calculate the `dt_month` based on the `txn_dt` using [`pyspark.sql.functions.trunc`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.trunc). something like: `df.where("dt_month = trunc(<some_date>, 'MON') and txn_dt = <some_date>")`

Comment: The reason is as I said that its part of a framework where I could pass any column to filter based on. I could also pass a dataset generation number which has a relationship with dt_month ofcourse but not as directly derivable. But if there was a partition level statistic keeping track of what the min and max gen_ds for a partition where it could be used to prune partitions to get very good performance which it now cant. But I cant derive the partitions where my gen_ds will be without keeping track of this statistic.

Comment: To add a little more context I dont pass a filter directly. Only a column to do iterative loads based on. So it will fetch the maximum value for that column in the destination and then get everything greater than that from the source and load it in. So I cant really say use the partition column as well without making it mandatory to use only date columns based on the partition column for such loads. I am not interesting in doing that.